# How to create WHERE IN clause with Zend_Db_Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

So I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status_id IN (1,3,4);
```

using Zend_Db_Select... can't find how to do it :( Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

you can also use it like this:

```
$data = array(1,3,4);
$select->where('status_id IN(?)', $data);
```

you dont need to implode array, and it's safer

Comment: Googled this problem and found your solution - then realized I had already upvoted it once. So since I can't upvote you again, take this comment as my token of appreciation!

Comment: So many variations on paramaterizing INs, thanks for saving my an evening of using google glopping!

Comment: Martin, I'd tried with implode, but saw that the whole string was quoted. thanks for providing a simple solution. Works like a charm!

Comment: This solution works for ZF1 but not for ZF2, see my other answer.

Comment: Not working for me after imploding the array. using zf2

Answer (score 13):

The first answer probably works in ZF1 but it doesn't work in Zend Framework 2:

```
$data = array(1,3,4);
$select->where('status_id IN(?)', $data);
```

In case the Zend Framework2 I found out that you have to use:

```
$data = array(1,3,4);
$select->where(array('status_id' => $data));
```

Result:

```
WHERE `status_id` IN ('1', '3', '4')
```

I couldn't find this documented anywhere! ZF documentation is generally sub-optimal.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the first answer: $select->where('status_id IN(?)', $data); really works in ZF1

Answer (score 8):

apparently it is super simple... stupid me:

```
$select->where('status_id IN(1,3,4)');
```

:(

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\In` with `Zend\Db\Sql\Where` to make a **where in** query inside a model.

```
$this->status_ids = array(1,3,4);

// select attributes from db by where in 
$result = $this->select(function (Select $select) {
   $predicate = new In();
   $select->where(
      $predicate->setValueSet($this->status_ids)
                ->setIdentifier('status_id')
      );
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$completionNo = implode(",",$data);

$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select()->from(array("p"=>PREFIX . "property_master"),array('id','completion_no','total_carpet_area'))->where("p.completion_no IN (?)", $completionNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This solution works well with zf2     
 $ids = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8');
 $select->where(array("app_post_id"=> $ids));
```

or

```
 $ids = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8');
    $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->from('app_post_comments');
        $select->where(array("app_post_id"=> $ids));

//        echo $select->getSqlString($this->adapter->getPlatform());
//        exit;
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $resultSet->initialize($result);
        $resultSet->buffer()->toArray();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($resultSet);
        exit;
        return $resultSet;
```