# How do you query using an "IN" WHERE clause with Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli::fetchAll()?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysqli

I'm having a strange problem with `Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli`. I need to query multiple items by ID from my database, so I have the following SQL,

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

This query works fine.

I then try and do this programatically with `Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli`,

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (?)';
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$result = $adapter->fetchAll($sql, implode(',', $ids));
```

The problem is for the above PHP I only get back 1 result instead of the expected 3. I've tried just passing the `$ids` instead of using `implode()`, but I just get an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but are there in fact rows in your database with ids 1, 2, and 3? :)

Comment: @Spiny Normal: Yes there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it helps, but here's an answer on how to do it using Zend_Db_Select: [How to create WHERE IN clause with Zend_Db_Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339714/how-to-create-where-in-clause-with-zend-db-select)

EDIT:

Ok, if it really doesn't work, and you were planning on using a string anyway, can't you just do this:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (%s)', implode(',' $ids));
$result = $adapter->fetchAll($sql);
```

:)

Or, even more wonderful:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (%s)', implode(',' array_fill('?', count($ids)));
$result = $adapter->fetchAll($sql, $ids);
```

However, I'm not sure fetchAll would accept this.

Comment: I saw that, but we can't use it as we use "SELECT SQL_CACHE" which you can't do using Zend_Db_Select.

Comment: RE Your Edit: Yeah, I've come to the conclusion I will have to bind it to the string manually before I throw it into fetchAll(). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy. See here:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?45,64588,66133#msg-66133

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get only one result is thanks to MySQL interpreting the string `'1,2,3'` as number `1`. You will explicitly have to add three question marks to the query:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?)';
$result = $adapter->fetchAll($sql, $ids);
```

You can write a function that will transform `$ids` to the right number of question marks.

Comment: The number of IDs is variable, so this approach will not work.

Comment: That's why I said to write a function to transform `$ids`.

Answer (score 0):

See this question/answer for a way to use the IN clause with a parameterized statement.

[I have an array of integers, how do I use each one in a mysql query (in php)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php)